# How to 'Post Follow' request in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request, href

I try to implement Slimpay payment solution API. But I have a problem during the process.

From this ressource (I got from a previous request) :

```
{
   "_links" : {
   "self" : {
           "href" : "https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/"
      },
    "profile" : {
           "href" : "https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/alps/v1"
     },
   "https://api.slimpay.net/alps#create-orders" : {
           "href" : "https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/orders"
     }

}
```

**How to Follow a Link on the last Resource to create a HTTP Post Request ?**

I have to POST this request :

```
 POST   Follow(https://api.slimpay.net/alps#create-orders)

 Accept: application/hal+json; profile="https://api.slimpay.net/alps/v1"
 Authorization: Bearer token
 Content-Type: application/json
```

**How should I write my request in Ajax ?**

I don't get the :

```
 POST   Follow(https://api.slimpay.net/alps#create-orders)
```

If I use :

```
     $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.slimpay.net/alps#create-orders',
            type: 'Post',           
            contentType: 'application/json,
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
            dataType: 'json',
```

==> this give a 401. It seems I lost the token.

Comment: Without a full explanation of your flow process for the complete handling of a payment it is not at all clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I try to follow this process : https://dev.slimpay.com/hapi/browser#create-orders  - I block on the step # Step: Follow a Link on the last Resource

Answer (score 0):

"Follow(namespace#relation)" means look for the `namespace#relation` key in the **_links** attribute of the last response you got from the server.

In your case, the last request you sent is: `GET    https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/` and you already quoted the response from the server. The actual URL is in the **href** property of the `https://api.slimpay.net/alps#create-orders` object. This is the URL you have to send your POST request to.

In other terms, `POST   https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/orders` is your next step in this case.

---

### Quick word about Hypermedia in REST APIs

Hypermedia is all about getting the entry point and then following relations from this entry point leaving the responsibility of building the URLs to the server.

It's kind of like a website where you would type the domain (e.g. stackoverflow.com) and then click on the links by using their name, not the actual URL behind. The URL may change, the name of the link won't, ever.

So just like you don't bookmark all the URLs of a website, you should not hard code URLs you got from the `_links` object.

This is a really quick idea of hypermedia, you can look for more information about it on the web.